# WooCommerce Cart API for Mobile Application

Tags: android, wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to WooCommerce. I want to add products to user's own cart. I googled a  lot for this but it seems cart API is not added in WooCommerce default API. So I added plugin called CoCart to my WooCommerce Admin. Now I am able to add product to cart but I don't for which user product is being added into cart and how can I retrieve cart items for  particular user. If its adding product to particular user  session then how I can manage it from Mobile Application. Also from Mobile Application I am able to add product to cart but again same issue that for which user's cart it is being added? Whenever I retrieve items from cart it sends me blank json array [].

Here are the APIs I am using:

**1. Add Product to cart:**

URL: https://www.my-domain.com/wp-json/wc/v2/cart/add

Method: POST

```
Parameters: {
  "product_id": "1111",
  "quantity": "1"
} 

Response:{
    "key": "af086cdab7954f1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "product_id": 1111,
    "variation_id": 0,
    "variation": [],
    "quantity": 1,
    "data": {},
    "data_hash": "b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896XXXXXXXXX",
    "line_tax_data": {
        "subtotal": [],
        "total": []
    },
    "line_subtotal": 50000,
    "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
    "line_total": 50000,
    "line_tax": 0
}
```

This API respond like this in postman and from Mobile app too.

**2. Retrieve cart items:**

URL: https://www.my-domain.com/wp-json/wc/v2/cart

Method: GET

Response: []

This API returns [] blank JSON array from Mobile application and from Postman it returns array of products from cart.

I don't know what is issue here. May be it works for session from web but what about mobile application? How can I use this APIs to work on Mobile platform.

1. How can I make my cart user specific using CoCart plugin?
2. If it requires to manage user session, how can I manage session for users from mobile app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of my own question.

It is somehow difficult to integrate WooCommerce store into Mobile Application without having prior knowledge of WooCommerce and its working criteria.

The issue why it was not syncing my cart with my current user was for cookie session for that particular user. I need to set cookie of that user in each API call header after login something like this:

```
    fetch(url1, {
              method: methodName,
              async: true,
              crossDomain: true,
              headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "cookie":"cookie value will goes here"
              }),
              body:data1
            })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more detail?Because same issue I have face, On every single add to cart button click it's create a new session.

Comment: You will receive a cookie on login. You need to store that and pass that value here as a cookie header.

Comment: later on I will manage with different way, Thanks for your response.

Comment: @AndiM I have used same plugin to retrieve cart content by using Rest API. But facing same issues as you. Can you please inform me where I need to do add your above mentioned set cookie code?

Comment: @Ketan, You have to use this code in a header wherever you call your user based API. I am using it in a fetch request

Comment: @AndiM, for User login/registration I have used this https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/ plugin. Can you please explain more about your solution. I really appreciate for your help :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with cocart, any suggestion to resolve this issue?
 

Please help me out guys @Dhruv

Comment: @kapilsingh the issue with mobile team side, when I checked in postman it's work perfect but when we call API in mobile device I have get different cookie.so mobile manage the cookie and problem is solved.